How to display products with the tag hot-sale to be displayed at the top of the product list in all sections
I want the products with the tag hot-sale to be displayed at the top of the product list on the Shop, Archive, Product Search Page, or any section where the product list is displayed, regardless of the sorting order, and then the other products to be displayed.
I have the following source code, but the problem is that it only displays products with the hot-sale tag and does not show other products:
function pre_get_posts_hot_product( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ( is_shop() || is_product_taxonomy() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ) {

        $hot_products_query = clone $query;

        $hot_products_query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'hot-sale',
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ) );

        $hot_products_query->set( 'fields', 'ids' );
        $hot_products_ids = $hot_products_query->get_posts();

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $hot_products_ids );

        $query->set( 'post__in', array_merge( $hot_products_ids, $query->get( 'post__not_in' ) ) );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_hot_product', 9999 );


What do you think about other conditions? As I checked you missed this conditions:

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() && ! $q->is_tax() ) return;

@Elnaz, Thank you, but I didn't fully understand how your response relates to my source code and my question, as my question was about something else. The issue I have is that only products with the hot-sale tag are being displayed, while I want the hot-sale tagged products to be shown first, followed by other products after them.

As I understand, you want to first display all the products with the tag "hot-sale" and then display other products. I think you must add other If conditions as I mentioned earlier. For that, if (! $q-> is_main_query() ) return; ..... Is it true?

@Elnaz, Yes, that’s exactly what I want. However, if possible, could you please specify where I should place your condition in my source code? Could you please provide a complete version of my source code with the solution you provided?

I had to write down here as an answer:
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() && ! $q->is_tax() ) return;
if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() || is_product_category() || 
  is_product_tag() ) {
$tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

$tax_query[] = array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
'field'    => 'slug',
'terms'    => array( 'hot-sale' ),
'operator' => 'IN',
);

$q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
$q->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
$q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

I add this one :
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_query');
function custom_modify_query($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_shop()) {
      $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
      $meta_query[] = array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
          'key' => '_sale_price',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
          'key' => '_sale_price',
          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
             )
         );
   $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
 }
 }

Besides that, go to WooCommerce plugin > Settings >Products and ensure there are no filters applied that limit the display to only sale items.

Please explain how this solves the issue please. Code-only answers are not good answers

Thank you again. But it still has the same initial problem, meaning it only displays the product(s) with the hot-sale tag and does not display the other products.

we must ensure that our query isn't filtering out non-sale items. You can adjust the meta_query to include all products. How should I bring the code in the comment?
